# what type of word would used to define having achieved a state?

Tags: verbs

... or more specifically is there a particular name for a verb in the past tense? for example the train has *arrived*, whereas the process of achieving the state would be to *arrive*

Comment: Enlightened? =P.

Answer (score 1):

*"Has arrived"* is simply an example of the [present perfect tense](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/verbtenseintro.html). If that's not what you were after, you'll need to clarify your question a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about the [past participle](http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/participlepast.htm). Example: to learn -> learned, to break -> broken.